# Python Selenium: Enumerate objects in canvas

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using `pyselenium` and my goal is to enumerate all objects on the canvas but I couldn't find a way how to do it. Any help would be appreciated. This is what my current code looks like:

```py
canvas = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//canvas[@style='touch-action: none; cursor: inherit;']").find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*")
    
for button in canvas:
    print(button)
```

I tried enumerating through all the children of the canvas but that did not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You must think about this holistically, and understand two things:

1. The nature of Canvas element: As an element `<canvas>` is a `bitmap` and it does not retain object information in the `DOM`, meaning that everything drawn is rasterized and from that you can conclude that individual objects that are drawn on a canvas can't be interacted with or queried after they are drawn (shortly said - `<canvas>` doesn't have child elements). To be more precise `selenium` can't directly enumerate or interact with the graphical objects drawn on a canvas), but it can simulate user interactions with the canvas element itself (clicks or mouse movements).
2. Canvas is dependant of JavaScript: To do anything (any interaction) on `<canvas>` contents you have to do it through JavaScript (`<canvas>` is usually controlled/manipulated using JavaScript APIs)

You are limited when it comes to this:

1. Modify/Extend JavaScript: In case you do have control over website's source code, consider modifying the JavaScript to expose the canvas objects state (for example: global variable, dedicated function, hidden DOM element which would store the state).
2. Analyzing the source code: By getting to know how canvas is being manipulated in the first place, you should be looking for JavaScript functions that handle drawing on the canvas, if you're lucky enough to have those functions maintain state or have access to the objects being drawn, you MIGHT be able to extract the information which you're looking for.

2.1. Since I mentioned to analyze the source code, `selenium` does have capability to execute JavaScript to interact with the canvas, which involve:

- Fetching the state of objects if they are stored in JavaScript variables;
- Triggering canvas events or, even invoking functions that could reveal more about the canvas state.

Example code:
`canvas_data = driver.execute_script("return getCanvasState();")`

Still, you would have to take in consideration edge cases, error handling AND in case that you're executing complex JavaScript or even dealing with large canvas, you'd have to count in performance issues.

Another approach is

Canvas interaction in a way where you would simulate user interactions with canvas, which is done through action chains in Selenium, then observe "side effects", when you interact with the canvas script is waiting response from another element on the page, that particular element would display information based on the interaction with the canvas, then you would read the text from the element, which would change depending on the interaction with the canvas, because as I said you have to do everything in JavaScript (to do changes on contents of canvas) - therefore, based on the movements it would update element in response to canvas events.

To apply this, you would have to examine if canvas that you're dealing with is triggering updates in other elements of the `DOM` when you're interacting with it, it could be hidden fields, divs,.. anything that reflects the state of canvas, then you would automate interactions by using `selenium` - it won't be simple either because you would need to experiment with different types of interactions (clicks, drags, etc..), depending on what the canvas supports.

Example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

# Assuming `driver` is your Selenium WebDriver instance
canvas = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("canvas.your-canvas-class")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(canvas).click().perform()
```

Then, you would retrive information after each interaction by checking the element(s) that get updated and extract necessary info.

```
info_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("your-info-box-xpath")
print(info_box.text)
```